# XMLPrime XLST.Compile throwing a null exception

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt

```
public static SqlXml XMLPrimeTransform(SqlXml inputDataXML, SqlXml inputTrasnformXML)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    XmlReader inxml = inputDataXML.CreateReader();
    XmlReader intrans = inputTrasnformXML.CreateReader();

    XmlReaderSettings xmlreadersettings = new XmlReaderSettings { NameTable = intrans.NameTable };

    XdmDocument document= new XdmDocument(inxml);

    XmlPrime.XsltSettings xsltSettings = new XmlPrime.XsltSettings(intrans.NameTable) { ContextItemType = XdmType.Node };

    var xslt = Xslt.Compile(intrans, xsltSettings);
    //var xslt = Xslt.Compile(inputTrasnformXML.CreateReader());

    var contextItem = document.CreateNavigator();
    var settings = new DynamicContextSettings { ContextItem = contextItem };

    xslt.ApplyTemplates(settings, ms);

    return new SqlXml(ms);
}
```

I wrote the above code function to apply a xlst 2.0 stylesheet to xml and return the XML. 
I tried to modify the XMLPrime example, but for some reason the line:

```
 var xslt = Xslt.Compile(intrans, xsltSettings);
```

is throwing a NullReferenceException. Both intrans and xsltSettings are not null. Anyone have any luck trying to accomplish this with XMLPrime or any other library?

Comment: Where do you declare and initialize that `Xslt` object whose `Compile` method you are trying to call?

Comment: It might also be necessary to set `ms.Position = 0` after the transformation and before you construct the SqlXml value of the stream.

Comment: Compile is a static method of XSLT.

http://www.xmlprime.com/xmlprime/doc/2.9/M_XmlPrime_Xslt_Compile_2_24fb5efd.htm

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bug specific to the stylesheet you are loading.  Try using a minimal stylesheet to see if that is the case.  If you think it is a bug in XmlPrime, contact the developers and supply a Visual Studio solution which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Same stylesheet and XML works just fine SAXON. I'll try contracting the developers